# backpack for laravel column width

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

Is it possible to reduce columns width for certain columns in backpack crud for laravel, is there any attribute in add columns that allows that?

On the image displayed , i want to swap the 1s for glyphicon-ok, but i can't find a way to do it

[image]

```
public function setup(){

    $this->crud->setModel("App\ReporteParamEstacion");
    $this->crud->setRoute("admin/reporte_paramestacion");
    // $this->crud->setRouteName("crud.reportes.listado_importacion");
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('parametro estacion', 'parametro estaciones');
    $this->crud->enableExportButtons();
    $this->crud->removeAllButtons();

     $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'nombre',
     'label' =>'Estacion',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'nombre_comuna',
     'label' =>'Comuna',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'MP10',
     'label' =>'MP10',
     'type' => 'text'


    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'MP25',
     'label' =>'MP25',
     'type' => 'text'

    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'SO2',
     'label' =>'SO2',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'NO2',
     'label' =>'NO2',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]); 

     $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'CO',
     'label' =>'CO',
     'type' => 'text'

    ]);  

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'O3',
     'label' =>'O3',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);

    $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'BC',
     'label' =>'BC',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);   

     $this->crud->addColumn([
     'name' => 'NOX',
     'label' =>'NOX',
     'type' => 'text'
    ]);  
 }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the check column type instead: https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types

Answer (score 0):

Set type to "check" like this:

`[`
   `'name' => 'mp10', // The db column name`
   `'label' => "MP10", // Table column heading`
   `'type' => 'check'`
`]`

Comment: is possible to reduce column width too?

Comment: I had to change from type check because i had problems to export in PDF, it seems icons can't be exported to pdf